# How to manually add custom data to behaviors

Tags: yii, yii2

I've use BlameableBehavior but in some of my controller I want to manually set the user created value but it can't work.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        BlameableBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

this not work.

```
$model->createdBy = 1;
$model->save();
```

it try to use the `BlameableBehavior`.

how can I manually add it.
Thanks.

Comment: Refer [BlameableBehavior  Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior.html) and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-blameable-behaviors--cms-23287.

Comment: What BlameableBehavior does is to set createdBy AUTOMATICALLY. Could you describe more why you would like to set it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use named behavior and detach it before saving model:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'blameable' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

And then:

```
$model->detachBehavior('blameable');
$model->createdBy = 1;
$model->save();
```